# Extra edges are generated between vertices when I move camera in game or in editor

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying generate custom procedural  landscape in unreal engine 4
To implement this I'm using this class https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/ProceduralMeshComponent/UProceduralMeshComponent/index.html
and for nice noise generation on Z axis I'm using this plugin https://github.com/devdad/SimplexNoise from this library the only method I use is: `USimplexNoiseBPLibrary::SimplexNoise2D`
How to implement whole process I inspired from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk
I will try to describe flow of whole process:

1. define vertices count in row and column
2. iterate through  row and column and create vertex vectors on (x*scale, y*scale, FMath::Lerp((-maxFallOff, maxHeight, USimplexNoiseBPLibrary::SimplexNoise2D(x*perlinScale,y*perlinScale)))
3. generate triangles using this method: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/ProceduralMeshComponent/UKismetProceduralMeshLibrary/ConvertQuadToTri-/index.html
4. generate UVs

That is all, at this point I can say everything works fine, but there is little issue, when I move camera in editor or in game on mesh appears extra edges. I also recorded video to show what I'm talking about.
https://youtube.com/watch?v=_B9Fxg5oZcE the edges I'm talking, appears on 00:05 second

Code is written in C++, I could post code here, but I think code is not problem here, I think something happens on runtime while I move camera something that I don't know...
I can say in advance if you interested that I'm not manipulating on mesh on Tick event

Comment: Using tessellation in your shader?

Comment: No, this happens no matter material is applied or not, in video that I've posted there is no material applied

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
Actually seems like I had bug in my code, I was passing too many triangle points to CreateMeshSection_LinearColor method that was the problem.
Anyway thanks for attention
Cheers